# Multiple Locations in Google Now

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, google-now

With Google Now, more specifically, the "time to home" card, is there a way that you can add more locations than Work and Home?

I found it set home by itself, and then later I stumbled upon how to set up a "work" location which I called school at the time. Now I would like to have a school location, a work location, my home location, and maybe even others if it is possible. Can this be done manually, or is it only automatic once Google Now suspects that I keep going to the same location several times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found that if I search for an address (or other location), not too long after that I get a card with driving directions to that location. If I tap the card, I'm asked if I "care about travel time to this location". Usually I say no, but if I say yes I'll have a new card that gives me the travel time to that location, just like for work or home.

In case you're wondering, the place to edit your work or home is `Settings | My stuff | Places...`. only home and work are available for me, but maybe they'll add some more custom locations in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Maps, you can save locations as favorites. They will eventually show up.